# Excel VBA Setting Named Range with a Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code that locates a specific column, and saves the Column Position as a Double. From there, I am trying to set a named range equal to it, below. When I run the code, I get the Run-time '1004' Error. Any ideas?

```
Sub namedRangeUpdate()
Dim namedRangeReference as double
namedRangeReference = ActiveCell.Column
ActiveWorkbook.Names("TM_New").RefersToR1C1 = "='Raw Data'!C" & namedRangeReference
End Sub
```

When I run the program, even though it errors on the last line, when I hover over `namedRangeReference`, it reflects `namedRangeReference = 32`. The code is getting that Column Number, but it's not making its way into the Named Range.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out; invalid coding. This works like a charm.

`ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="TM_New", RefersToR1C1:="='Raw Data'!C" & namedRangeReference`